# Link to external URL documentation from doxygen-style Objective-C comments

Tags: ios, xcode, documentation, doxygen

I want to write something similar to this:

```
/**
 Post a review. (For every place belongs only one review. If it was already written, the previous one will be overwritten.)

 @param placeId Place identifier
 @param rating Rating 0-5 for the place
 @param review The text the user entered for review
 @param callback Gets called either when the network request succeeds or when fails for some reason. The `success` parameter indicates this. If success is true, the contents of the `data` parameter of the response is given back as the `response` parameter. If the request fails, then only the `error` parameter is filled. You can find the details in this object.

 @see http://example.com/api/v1/doc/service/review/saveReview?pkey=t75jg-5uGse-qIo
 */
- (void)saveReviewFor:(NSNumber *)placeId rating:(NSUInteger)rating review:(NSString *)review callback:(VMNetworkCallback)callback;
```

The problem is, that the link at the `@see` tag is not clickable in Xcode help bubbles:

[image: Xcode screenshot]

Is it possible to have a clickable documentation link in this view? What syntax shall I use?

Answer (score 1):

Yes it is possible to do so,
Change your `@see` tag to be as follow:

```
@see <http://example.com/api/v1/doc/service/review/saveReview?pkey=t75jg-5uGse-qIo>
```

For more information you can read the relevant section at Doxygen Documentation
[Markdown support -> Automatic Linking](https://www.doxygen.nl/manual/markdown.html#md_autolink)